# UITableViewCell doesn't pickup UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue when adding CAGradientLayer sublayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a UITableViewCell that I've added a gradient to by using CAGradientLayer.  This works fine, but the table cell doesn't turn blue when selected, even after setting it's selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue.  If I don't add the gradient layer, it works fine.

Is there a way to make these items work together?

Here's my code inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    //cell gradient        
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 50);
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:245/255.0 blue:245/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                       (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:247/255.0 green:247/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor],
                       nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00],
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.50],
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.51],
                          (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],                                                                                          
                          nil];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];


    //bring back rounded corners by creating a masklayer 
    UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:gradient.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomRight|UIRectCornerBottomLeft cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8, 8)];
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = gradient.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    gradient.mask = maskLayer;

    //add the cell shadow
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be putting the gradient over the view that changes when it is selected- the UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue view may be appearing, but you just cannot see it (a way to test it out is only have the gradient cover part of your cell- if the other part changes color when it is selected, then this is the issue).

If this is the issue, then you could do your own custom drawing for the cell when it is selected by subclassing UITableViewCell, or you could have the gradient disappear whenever the cell is selected (and reappear when the cell is deselected).

Comment: That is what's going on.  I made the frame for the gradient half as wide and the half w/out the gradient turned blue.  Would I need to try and remove the gradient in touchesBegan ?

Comment: I don't think so. I would subclass UITableViewCell and set the gradient in the init method, then override the `setSelected:animated:` method, removing the gradient if selected==true and then calling `[super setSelected:animated:]` to let the super class draw the blue gradient.

Comment: As a follow up to this, I actually wanted setHighlighted, not setSelected.  setSelected seems to occur much later than setHighlighted, which occurs right when the touch begins.

Comment: setHighlighted didn't work for me. I tried both and setSelected worked.